# Possible to get the total count of sent messages by day for a single campaign?

Tags: mailgun

I want to look at a longitudinal summary of a single campaign, `CampaignA`.

I want to do something like:

```
curl -s --user "api:0123456789" -G https://api.mailgun.net/v2/example.mailgun.org/campaigns/CampaignA/events?groupby=day&event='sent'
```

but this is not supported in the API.

Does anyone know of an alternative way to get this information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you attach a tag to your campaign when you send it you can then retrieve all campaigns with that tag.
So per each daya you can have a different campaign tag and then filter these on the sent event or maybe delivered event.
Have a look here: http://documentation.mailgun.com/api-events.html#filter-event

Answer (score 0):

Why do you say that is not supported?

See here: https://documentation.mailgun.com/api-campaigns.html#events

Comment: Sorry! I understand now. @API_sheriff_orlie it's right!